# Design patterns for data source independent model?

Tags: php, design-patterns, datasource

Say I want to build an application in which models could have different data sources (like MySQL, some API, XML, etc).

What would be the most common approache(s) in order to implement something like this, and what design patterns would be used?

Answer (score 2):

I think [DAO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) is what you are looking for.

Think like:

```
interface RdbmsDriver {
    public function connect();
    public function disconnect();
    public function query($sql);
    public function fetchAll($sql);
}

class MysqliDriver implements RdbmsDriver {
    public function connect() { }
    public function disconnect() { }
    public function query($sql) { }
    public function fetchAll($sql) { }    
}

class PgsqlDriver implements RdbmsDriver {
    public function connect() { }
    public function disconnect() { }
    public function query($sql) { }
    public function fetchAll($sql) { }    
}

abstract class RdbmsDao {
    protected $driver;

    public function __construct(RdbmsDriver $driver) {
        $this->driver = $driver;
    }
}


interface SomeEntityDao {
    public function insert(SomeEntity entity);
    public function update(SomeEntity entity);
    public function delete(SomeEntity entity);
    public function find($entityKey);
    public function findAll();
}

/**
 * Data from relational databases.
 */
class SomeEntityRdbmsDao extends RdbmsDao implements SomeEntityDao {
    public function insert(SomeEntity entity) { }
    public function update(SomeEntity entity) { }
    public function delete(SomeEntity entity) { }
    public function find($entityKey) { }
    public function findAll() { }
}

// Use like: new SomeEntityRdbmsDao(new MysqliDriver(...))

/**
 * Data from a webservice
 */
class SomeEntityWebServiceDao implements SomeEntityDao {
    public function insert(SomeEntity entity) { }
    public function update(SomeEntity entity) { }
    public function delete(SomeEntity entity) { }
    public function find($entityKey) { }
    public function findAll() { }    
}

class SomeEntityModel {
    private $persistance;
    public function __construct(SomeEntityDao $persistance) {
        $this->persistance = $persistance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) approach.
The mapper is not restricted to databases, it could handle any datasource (file, db, xml, api etc.)

The most important thing is to have your Domain Model separated from the data source. To make the mapper truly interchangeable can be a hard thing, because the datasources are of a different kind. A XML source is not writeable, so you cannot implement an insert method for example.